# Remove part numbering on TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, books, parts

I'm currently using `\documentclass{book}` and I'd like to remove the roman numeral before the parts of my TOC. It currently looks like this:

[image]

What I did before was use `\part*` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{this is the first part}` but I figured that I need the `\part` numbering for a different code thus, I have to strictly use `\part`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the starred version if you want no part label to appear in the `toc`. With the `newlinetospace` option, it is needless to use the optional argument to remove a line break in titles: it is automatically converted to a horizontal space in table of contents and headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[newlinetospace, newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{}{}{1em}{\sffamily\huge}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]
    {\vspace{2em}\large\bfseries\sffamily\relax}
    {\contentslabel[\relax]{0em}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
    Bla

\part{Example 1:\\Foo}%
    Bla

\part{Example 2:\\Bar}%[
    Bla

\part{Appendix}
    Bla

\end{document}
```

Does this suit your requirements?

If you feel the answer is as per your requirements please upvote the answer by clicking on the red triangle at the left and the tick mark below it

Comment: amazing!! this works really well! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can patch `\@part` (defined in [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co)) and remove the insertion of `\thepart` and the subsequent space (`\hspace{1em}`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

\end{document}
```